# How to update subdocument mongoose with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
console.log("check")
 
Email.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.idUser, "sendedEmail.emailId": req.params.idEmail},
    { 
        $set: {
            "sendedEmail.$.isSeen": true
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
);

var emailList = await Email.find()

res.send(emailList)
```

it work fine with localhost, but in vps it doesn't change anything

sorry for my bad english

Comment: can you share schema of email

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar 


`const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var emailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 subscriberEmail: String,
 sendedEmail: Array,
 },
    {
     versionKey: false
    }
)

var Email = mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema, 'emails');

module.exports = Email;`

Answer (score 1):

modify this line: var Email = mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema). Mongoose will make a collection called: 'emails'

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var emailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({     subscriberEmail: String,    sendedEmail: Array,     },     {        versionKey: false     } )  
var Email = mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema); 
module.exports = Email;
```

Try this syntax with findById() method:

```js
updateEmail: (req, res) => {
        let Id = req.params.id;
        Email.findById(Id, (err, res) =>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error to find'});        
        }); 

        let update = req.body;
        Email.findByIdAndUpdate(Id, update, {new: true}, (err, EmailUpdated) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error while updating'});
            if(!EmailUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'Email doesnt exist'});
            return res.status(200).send({email: EmailUpdated});
        });
    },
```

Comment: Its still doesn't change anything, this is my schema after modify

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

`var emailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 subscriberEmail: String,
 sendedEmail: Array,
 },
    {
     versionKey: false
    }
)

var Email = mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema);

module.exports = Email;`